# вывести слово по частям в порядке возрастания.Python

Tags: python, циклы

не получается решить данную задачу.

задача: программа, которая запрашивает у пользователя строку, а затем печатает все строки, начиная с первого символа по длине.

должно быть :

```
word: testi
    t
    te
    tes
    test
    testi
```

мой код:

```
s=input("word: ")
while len(s)>0:
    print(s[0])
    s=s[1:]
```

Cпасибо

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проходимся по каждому символу в строке:

```
s = input("word: ")
for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[:i + 1])
```

Comment: А как можно в обратном порядке вывести слово _?

i
ti
sti
esti
testi